# How to keep OS working when the laptop's lid is closed for Peppermint?

Tags: power-management, suspend, peppermint

For Peppermint 11.6 bullseye - which it is based on Debian - for 32 bits

I want to reach the following behavior:

- When the laptop's lid is closed,
  the OS still working (but with the screen as black).

So far I can do this approach for Ubuntu, according to [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid), but does not work for Peppermint.

Just in case, the following instructions were applied:

1. Open the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file
2. Edit from `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`
3. Execute the `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` command
4. Do login again, if it remains in black with underscore in white:
   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and do login again

Even when restarted the OS,
the desired behavior did not work as indicated. 
Of course, it worked for Ubuntu,
but not for Peppermint – remember both are based on Debian.

How to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the provided answer, it brought me the final guidance, therefore the correct setting is:

```
Menu
 Settings
  Power Manager
   System
    Plugged in <--- very important
     Laptop Lid
      Switch off display
```

Answer (score 1):

depending on if you picked the xfce or gnome version of peppermint the steps below are roughly the same

```
System > Preferences > Power Management


On AC Power (On Battery Power) > Actions


When laptop lid is closed:Do Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks it brought me the correct guidance